# Ember component is not re-rendering on change of @tracked variable

Tags: javascript, ember.js

My UserTag component is only re-rendering on page refresh. I expect it to refresh when action `saveRoles(updatedUserRoles)` is used, since it depends on an `@tracked` variable.
UserRoles is a component from an imported dependency in package.json.

UserTag component:

```
export default class UserTag extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super(...arguments);
    this.tags = this.updateTags(this.args.tags);
  }

  @tracked tags;

  updateTags(tags) {
    if (tags) {
      if (!Array.isArray(tags)) tags = Array.of(tags);
      return tags.map((tag, index) => this.createTag(tag, index));
    }

    return tags;
  }
...
```

Defined in my template:

```
<UserTag @tags={{this.sortedUserRoles}} />
```

In my controller:

```
  @tracked persistedRoles = null;

  @computed('persistedRoles')
  get sortedUserRoles() {
    console.log('sorting user roles...');
    return this.persistedRoles.sort();
  }

  @action
  saveRoles(updatedUserRoles) {
    ... // Some manipulating of updated roles for AJAX call

    this.persistedRoles = [...updatedUserRoles];
  }
```

I've tried adding a `console.log` in `sortedUserRoles()` to see if it is being called when I save permissions, but it is not being used. If I add `{{this.sortedUserRoles}}` outside of the `@tags=...`, it is called and the sorted roles are shown, which leads me to believe it ignored the tracking when set to a property for a component. Is this the case? (Note: `@tags` is `@tracked` in `<UserTag>`)

Versions:

"ember-cli": 3.22.0

"ember-data": "~3.18.0"

Comment: can you share the `UserTag` component? Is it a glimmer component? if yes you can not have `@tags` tracked (also you should not do this) because it will become `this.args.tags` not `this.tags`. And how do you *use* `this.args.tags`? This is important, it will only be tracked when you actually *use* it somewhere.

Comment: I think the `@computed` decorator converts the native getter in a computed property and adds caching. That might cause problems depending how that computed property is consumed in `<UserTag>` component. I would recommend to not use `@computed` with tracked properties. If you want the getter to be cached have a look at [ember-cached-decorator-polyfill](https://github.com/ember-polyfills/ember-cached-decorator-polyfill) instead.

Comment: @Lux I've edited my original question to have some of the UserTag component. It is a glimmer component, but uses `this.args.tags` in the constructor to set it to `this.tags`.

Answer (score 4):

Your problem is that you copy `this.args.tags` to `this.tags` in the constructor. This code only runs *once*.

```
this.tags = this.updateTags(this.args.tags);
```

So later when you do

```
this.persistedRoles = ...
```

you only update `this.args.tags` but not `this.tags`. And because `this.args.tags` is not used in the template `sortedUserRoles` is not used either and so ember will have no reason to call the getter.

So the solution is to use `this.args.tags` in your component directly. If you need to transform the data use a getter:

```
get tags() {
  let tags = this.args.tags;
  if (tags) {
    if (!Array.isArray(tags)) tags = Array.of(tags);
    return tags.map((tag, index) => this.createTag(tag, index));
  }

  return this.args.tags;
}
```

Also remove the `@computed('persistedRoles')`.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense that is only being run once. Although I switched to using `this.args.tags` in my UserTag template, and I see `sortedUserRoles` is being used, but the `tags` array is empty (no tags are rendered). I must be missing something?

Comment: I think I need `this.tags` in the template, though. Or at least I need a way to update and remove (I currently have a `removeTag(tag)` function too) tags from the component's state. `this.args.tags` is immutable, so I can't update the state this way.

Comment: do not update but create a getter that uses `this.args.tags` and returns whatever you need, and then use this property in your template. Like I showed above with the `tags` getter.